# How to build a calendar in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I want to build a week calendar (with options to toggle bewteen month and day visions) in a Rails 4 app.

I know that I can use a JS calendar, like FullCalendar, but, I dont know how to do this and if this will overload the client-side when i get a lot of events.

I tried to search about it, but I cant find nothing.

I used data_builder and did the month vision, but I want do this to a week vision too.

Can someone give me a hint or show me how to do this?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised

Comment: I cant see the revised one, cause I dont have an account :(

Comment: Sorry but that railscast is not what I want. Its only shows how to do a month view. I need a week view (with events by time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at this, that was just relased: https://gorails.com/blog/simplecalendar-1-1-released